# What could this star-like object in the morning sky have been?

Tags: astronomy

At sunrise this morning and yesterday morning, around 6:45 am in Chicago, a bright light appeared in the eastern sky over Lake Michigan. It twinkled like a star, but it was much larger and brighter than a star. I think planets don't shine, so it wasn't a planet. It appeared a little less than half-way up to the sky. It didn't move, so it wasn't a plane. Could it have been a satellite? I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: How sure are you about the time, direction, and altitude? Did you actually see the object appear and/or disappear, or was it there the whole time? How long did you see it?

Comment: This post better suited for the Astronomy stack. But your morning star was probably Venus. Does it appear the same time very day?

Comment: To clarify, planets will shine, just like the moon, from reflected sun light. Given their apparent size and distance, they can also appear to look like relatively bright stars too (actually some of the [brightest!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_brightest_stars#Measurement)). You've probably looked at a planet at one point in your life, without even knowing it. I'm not saying it is a planet, but it very well could be as @docscience mentioned.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Astronomy SE as asserted by docscience.

Comment: @user36790 Astronomy questions are [on topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/if-its-possible-do-we-want-to-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-astrono) here, and across the entire network "would be better elsewhere" is not a sufficient reason to close a question -- it must actually be off topic at the original site.

Comment: @docscience Venus is [only just rising at 6:15 in Chicago](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/aa_mrst2.pl?form=1&ID=AA&year=2016&month=3&day=19&reps=5&body=2&state=IL&place=Chicago&height=) right now, so it wouldn't be more than 10 degrees above the horizon. Of course the altitude may be misestimated. A better match to altitude (though worse in direction) would be Saturn.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: Don't you think it is more competent there? I would like to vote it to migrate it there but since there is no option, I had to cite that reason; question of on-topic is not really required as we know Astronomy is on-topic here. What I'm saying is that it is __more__ competent there.

Comment: There is plenty of astronomy software around that can show you what the sky would have looked like at that time. Yesterday, 6:45am the sun would have been up, already, Venus and Mercury would have been too close to the sun to be visible, IMHO. Towards the West Saturn, Mars and Arcturus would have been close together and Vega would have been roughly halfway up in the sky.

Comment: @CuriousOne - Sunrise in Chicago on March 21, 2016 occurred at 6:51 AM. The Sun would not have already been up, but the pre-sunrise sky would have been fairly bright. To the questioner: One possibility that no one has mentioned is that you might well have been seeing the Sun reflecting off of an airplane far to the east.

Comment: You might want to check http://www.amsmeteors.org/members/imo_view/browse_reports?event=PENDING, especially http://www.amsmeteors.org/members/imo_view/report/84501 and http://www.amsmeteors.org/members/imo_view/report/84500 to see if it was a meteor (both reports are within 5 minutes of the time you specify, and are in the Central USA).

Comment: @DavidHammen: Oops... you are right, I missed daylight savings time and the software I was using has one hour bug relative to UTC!  :-) Venus might have been visible towards the East.

Comment: Have a look http://www.astronomyufo.com/UFO/Venusufo.htm